# Remove Children Of a Different Class As3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have added many objects to the stage (in the Achievements.as class) to create an achievements board. I want to remove all of the children from the main.as class when someone presses a back button is there a way of doing this. Also, is there a way of creating a custom textField class where each *textField.selectable = false* without having to assign it to each one individually.

```
public static var texts:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
public static var titleTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
public static var descripTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
public static var rewardTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
public static var achCoins:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();

for (var j:int = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            achCoins[j].x = 240;
            achCoins[j].y = 45 + j * 70;
            addChild(achCoins[j]);
            descripTxt[j].x = 0;
            descripTxt[j].y = 30 + 70 * j;
            //descripTxt[j].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
            descripTxt[j].defaultTextFormat = tf2;
            descripTxt[j].text = descriptext[j];
            descripTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
            addChild(descripTxt[j]);
            titleTxt[j].x = 0;
            titleTxt[j].y = j * 70;
            //titleTxt[j].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
            titleTxt[j].defaultTextFormat = tf3;
            titleTxt[j].text = titletext[j];
            titleTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
            addChild(titleTxt[j]);
            rewardTxt[j].x = 200;
            rewardTxt[j].y = 30 + j * 70;
            rewardTxt[j].text = reward[j].toString();
            rewardTxt[j].setTextFormat(tf1);
            rewardTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
            rewardTxt[j].textColor = 0x000000;
            addChild(rewardTxt[j]);
            texts[j].text = Main.achievement[j] + "/" + totnum[j];
            texts[j].setTextFormat(tf1);
            texts[j].x = 200;
            texts[j].y = j * 70;
            texts[j].embedFonts = true;
            addChild(texts[j]);

        }
```

I then remove the children using this code

```
for (var k:int = 0; k < 30; k++)
        {
            removeChild(achievementback.descripTxt[k]);
            removeChild(achievementback.titleTxt[k]);
            removeChild(achievementback.rewardTxt[k]);
            removeChild(achievementback.texts[k]);

        }
```

I get the error

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property descripTxt through a
>   reference with static type Achievements.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            texts.push(new TextField());
            titleTxt.push(new TextField());
            rewardTxt.push(new TextField());
            descripTxt.push(new TextField());
            achCoins.push(new coinSmall());
        {
```

In Achievements.as Class

```
public function RemoveTextboxes(){
for (var k:int = 0; k < 30; k++)
    {
       removeChild(descripTxt[k]);
       removeChild(titleTxt[k]);
       removeChild(rewardTxt[k]);
       removeChild(texts[k]);
    }
}
```

In Main.as Class

```
achievementback.RemoveTextBoxes()
```

Here is my whole achievements class

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
public class Achievements extends MovieClip
{
    public var backRect:Shape = new Shape();
    public var coinsmall:MovieClip = new coinSmall();
    public var titleText:MyTextField = new MyTextField();
    public var descripText:MyTextField = new MyTextField();
    public var reward_txt:MyTextField = new MyTextField();
    public static var texts:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
    public static var titleTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
    public static var descripTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
    public static var rewardTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
    public static var achCoins:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
    public var tf1:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    public var tf2:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    public var tf3:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    //Achievement Variables
    public var descriptext:Array = new Array();
    public static var acharr:Array = new Array();
    public var titletext:Array = new Array();
    public var reward:Array = new Array(25,50,250,500,200,2000,10,100,500,10,25,50,10,25,100,25,25,50,50,100,500,500,5,5,5,50,10,50,100,250);


    public function Achievements()
    {
        //Defining Objects
        //Set Up Text Formats
        //Text Format 1
        tf1.font = "Myriad pro";
        tf1.size = 20;
        tf1.color = 0x660000;
        tf1.align = "right";
        //Text Format 2
        tf2.size = 16;
        tf2.color = 0xB8461D;
        tf2.font = "Myriad Pro";
        tf2.align = "center";
        //Text Format 3
        tf3.size = 23;
        tf3.color = 0x660000;
        tf3.font = "Myriad Pro";
        tf3.align = "center";
        //Text Box: Fraction Completed

        //Text Box: Reward Amount For Each Achievement
        //Text Box: Description of Achievement

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            texts.push(new TextField());
            titleTxt.push(new TextField());
            rewardTxt.push(new TextField());
            descripTxt.push(new TextField());
            achCoins.push(new coinSmall());
            backRect.graphics.beginFill(0x86B46D, 0.7);
            backRect.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, i*70, 300, 60, 10, 10);
            backRect.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(backRect);
        }

        //change the text in a loop;
        var acharr:Array = new Array();
        var totnum:Array = new Array(50,100,500,1000,5,10,10,100,500,25,50,100,1,1,3,1,50,100,50,100,2,5,5,5,5,20,10,50,100,250);
        for (var j:int = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            achCoins[j].x = 240;
            achCoins[j].y = 45 + j * 70;
            addChild(achCoins[j]);
            descripTxt[j].width = 225;
            descripTxt[j].height = 30;
            descripTxt[j].x = 0;
            descripTxt[j].y = 30 + 70 * j;
            //descripTxt[j].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
            descripTxt[j].defaultTextFormat = tf2;
            descripTxt[j].text = descriptext[j];
            descripTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
            addChild(descripTxt[j]);
            titleTxt[j].width = 225;
            titleTxt[j].height = 30;
            titleTxt[j].x = 0;
            titleTxt[j].y = j * 70;
            //titleTxt[j].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
            titleTxt[j].defaultTextFormat = tf3;
            titleTxt[j].text = titletext[j];
            titleTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
            addChild(titleTxt[j]);
            rewardTxt[j].width = 100;
            rewardTxt[j].height = 30;
            rewardTxt[j].selectable = false;
            rewardTxt[j].x = 200;
            rewardTxt[j].y = 30 + j * 70;
            rewardTxt[j].text = reward[j].toString();
            rewardTxt[j].setTextFormat(tf1);
            rewardTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
            rewardTxt[j].textColor = 0x000000;
            addChild(rewardTxt[j]);
            texts[j].text = acharr[j] + "/" + totnum[j];
            texts[j].setTextFormat(tf1);
            texts[j].width = 100;
            texts[j].height = 30;
            texts[j].selectable = false;
            texts[j].x = 200;
            texts[j].y = j * 70;
            texts[j].embedFonts = true;
            addChild(texts[j]);

        }
    }
public function RemoveTextboxes(){
for (var k:int = 0; k < 30; k++)
    {
       removeChild(descripTxt[k]);
       removeChild(titleTxt[k]);
       removeChild(rewardTxt[k]);
       removeChild(texts[k]);
    }
}}
```

}
The arrays descriptext:Array  acharr:Array  titletext:Array All have the correct content in them but it is a lot of text so I took it out to post this

Here is the code I am using to remove the children from Main.as

```
function achievementExit():void
    {
        removeChild(back1);
        removeChild(coin_sm);
        removeChild(coinAmt);
        removeChild(completed);
        removeChild(achTit);
        removeChild(achback);
        achievementback.RemoveTextBoxes()
        removeChild(achievementback)
        removeChild(scrollPane);
    }
```

Comment: are you removing them before they are added?

Comment: @Xela I am removing them after but in a different class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to slightly modify the code and comment out where you set the text in the boxes to get this to run (since I'm missing some code) But What seemed to be my issue is that the textboxes were getting removed but your green shape was staying on the stage. Added a vector to hold all those and added those to the remove function.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
    public class Achievements extends MovieClip
    {
        public var coinsmall:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        public var titleText:TextField = new TextField();
        public var descripText:TextField = new TextField();
        public var reward_txt:TextField = new TextField();
        public static var texts:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
        public static var titleTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
        public static var descripTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
        public static var rewardTxt:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();
        public static var achCoins:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
        public static var graphix:Vector.<Shape> = new Vector.<Shape>();
        public var tf1:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        public var tf2:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        public var tf3:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        //Achievement Variables
        public var descriptext:Array = new Array();
        public static var acharr:Array = new Array();
        public var titletext:Array = new Array();
        public var reward:Array = new Array(25,50,250,500,200,2000,10,100,500,10,25,50,10,25,100,25,25,50,50,100,500,500,5,5,5,50,10,50,100,250);


        public function Achievements()
        {
            //Defining Objects
            //Set Up Text Formats
            //Text Format 1
            tf1.font = "Myriad pro";
            tf1.size = 20;
            tf1.color = 0x660000;
            tf1.align = "right";
            //Text Format 2
            tf2.size = 16;
            tf2.color = 0xB8461D;
            tf2.font = "Myriad Pro";
            tf2.align = "center";
            //Text Format 3
            tf3.size = 23;
            tf3.color = 0x660000;
            tf3.font = "Myriad Pro";
            tf3.align = "center";

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                descriptext.push("THIS IS " + i);
                texts.push(new TextField());
                titleTxt.push(new TextField());
                rewardTxt.push(new TextField());
                descripTxt.push(new TextField());
                achCoins.push(new MovieClip());
                var backRect:Shape = new Shape();
                backRect.graphics.beginFill(0x86B46D, 0.7);
                backRect.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, i*70, 300, 60, 10, 10);
                backRect.graphics.endFill();
                graphix.push(backRect);
                addChild(backRect);
            }

            //change the text in a loop;
            var acharr:Array = new Array();
            var totnum:Array = new Array(50,100,500,1000,5,10,10,100,500,25,50,100,1,1,3,1,50,100,50,100,2,5,5,5,5,20,10,50,100,250);
            for (var j:int = 0; j < 30; j++)
            {
                achCoins[j].x = 240;
                achCoins[j].y = 45 + j * 70;
                addChild(achCoins[j]);
                descripTxt[j].width = 225;
                descripTxt[j].height = 30;
                descripTxt[j].x = 0;
                descripTxt[j].y = 30 + 70 * j;
                //descripTxt[j].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
                descripTxt[j].defaultTextFormat = tf2;
                //descripTxt[j].text = descriptext[j];
                descripTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
                addChild(descripTxt[j]);
                titleTxt[j].width = 225;
                titleTxt[j].height = 30;
                titleTxt[j].x = 0;
                titleTxt[j].y = j * 70;
                //titleTxt[j].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
                titleTxt[j].defaultTextFormat = tf3;
                //titleTxt[j].text = titletext[j];
                titleTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
                addChild(titleTxt[j]);
                rewardTxt[j].width = 100;
                rewardTxt[j].height = 30;
                rewardTxt[j].selectable = false;
                rewardTxt[j].x = 200;
                rewardTxt[j].y = 30 + j * 70;
                //rewardTxt[j].text = reward[j].toString();
                rewardTxt[j].setTextFormat(tf1);
                rewardTxt[j].embedFonts = true;
                rewardTxt[j].textColor = 0x000000;
                addChild(rewardTxt[j]);
                //texts[j].text = acharr[j] + "/" + totnum[j];
                texts[j].setTextFormat(tf1);
                texts[j].width = 100;
                texts[j].height = 30;
                texts[j].selectable = false;
                texts[j].x = 200;
                texts[j].y = j * 70;
                texts[j].embedFonts = true;
                addChild(texts[j]);

            }
        }

        public function RemoveTextboxes(){
        trace("removing")
        for (var k:int = 0; k < 30; k++)
            {
               removeChild(descripTxt[k]);
               removeChild(titleTxt[k]);
               removeChild(rewardTxt[k]);
               removeChild(texts[k]);
                removeChild(graphix[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also had to change your custom classes back to MovieClip and TextBox since I didnt have source for those.

Comment: how would you remove them from the main class?

Comment: I thought you were trying to remove textfields in Main.as. If you are wanting to remove textfields that are in Achievement.as from the Main.as you could add a method to your class Achievement.as called RemoveTextboxes() and then from Main.as you can call myAchievementClassInstance.RemoveTextBoxes();

Comment: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method RemoveTextBoxes through a reference with static type Achievements.

Comment: Can you post your entire Achievement Class? It's hard to pinpoint the issue without all the context. Based on the error i would guess your class is static?

Comment: I added the code The arrays descriptext:Array  acharr:Array  titletext:Array All have the correct content in them but it is a lot of text so I took it out to post this

Comment: Still getting the error 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method RemoveTextBoxes through a reference with static type Achievements.

Comment: I posted the code I am using to call the remove function from the Main.as Class.

Comment: So is this how you are creating the instance of the class? var achievementback = new Achievments();

Comment: yeah public var achievementback = new Achievements(); and now I am getting the error Property RemoveTextBoxes not found on Achievements and there is no default value.

Comment: Shouldn't think its a property, do you have the () after RemoveTextBoxes()

Comment: Perhaps you could file share this whole project?

Comment: Thanks for all the help but I'm just going to do it a different way

Comment: I'm using Adobe Flash CS5 if that means anything

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
for (var k:int = 0; k < 30; k++)
        {
            achievementback.removeChild(achievementback.descripTxt[k]);
            achievementback.removeChild(achievementback.titleTxt[k]);
            achievementback.removeChild(achievementback.rewardTxt[k]);
            achievementback.removeChild(achievementback.texts[k]);
        }
```

**Update**
Are you even adding those DisplayObjects to your vector arrays?

Comment: It gets the same error as the one I originally posted

Comment: Are you even adding those DisplayObjects to your vector arrays?

Comment: Wait sorry I stand corrected your just initializing it another way. Try push it to the vector after addChild just to see.

Comment: RangeError: Error #1125: The index 0 is out of range 0. Thanks for the help in all of this.

Comment: change it all to something like this:
var descrip = new TextBox();
descrip.x = 0;
            descrip.y = 30 + 70 * j;
            descrip.defaultTextFormat = tf2;
            descrip.text = "test";
            descrip.embedFonts = true;
            addChild(descrip);
  descripTxt.push(descrip);

Comment: I am still getting the same possibly undefined error

Comment: dunno, your prob gonna need to give me the whole source for me to fix it.

Comment: The achievements code is added as a child to a scrollpane don't know if that is important. I add it to the stage then make it the scroll panes source.